# How do I duplicate a content on the page onclick in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

In my view, I have form fields that were fetched from the database

```
<select id="part_id_01", name="part_id_01">
    <option value="1">top</option>
    <option value="2">middle</option>
    <option value="3">bottom</option>
    <option value="4">none</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="part_color_01" name="part_color_01">
```

I will have a button on the page that when clicked, it will add another pair of these fields with an increment number on the names and ids. I don't want to get the fields through the database every time because they were just fixed data, so I want to simply copy the contents that were already on the page and paste it. How do I do this duplication in React?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Div extends Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.setState({
    array:[]
  })
  this.manangeDiv = this.manangeDiv.bind(this);
}
manangeDiv(e,type){
  let array = this.state.array;
  if (type=='add') {
    //this line will duplicate the object of array and push it in to same array
    array.push(array[0]);
  }
  else if(type=='remove') {
    array.splice(0,1);
  }
  this.setState({
    array
  })
}
render(){
  return(
    <div>
      {/* Add button will increase array length by one, and Remove button will decrease array length by one */}
      <button onClick={(e)=>this.manangeDiv(e,'add')}> add </button>  <button onClick={(e)=>this.manangeDiv(e,'remove')}> remove </button>
      {
        //this map funtion will create dynamic loop on the basis of array length
        this.state.array.map((item,index)=>{
          return(
            <div key={index}> Dynamic Div </div>
          );
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
}
}
```

This is the simplest approach to this stuff. Make an empty array and assign your first data object into it , after that create add remove button and on button call check if add button clicked or remove button clicked. if add button click just push the same object in array and splice it in case of remove button click.
In render part map array and in return of map define your div which will create your div dynamically on the basis of your array length hence, you can add and delete div on clicking buttons.